# How to add my project to multiple GCP resource locations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, bucket

I have built a firebase project which has "asia-south1" as its default GCP location, I choose this location because other servers had too much latency. But now I want the application to work in other countries as well, The data of one GCP location will also be accessed by others if we have multiple firebase projects and now I have really no idea how to proceed, your help would be really appreciated.

Hope I was able to clear the question

Thank you

Comment: Hello @Anubhav. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Another option is to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is useful for you. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Anubhav, I just updated my current answer, I hope could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your Cloud Firestore data can be kept in either a regional or a multi-regional location. The developer must choose a location when Firestore is enabled in a project.

The only way for a developer to alter the location of data in an existing project is to start a new Firestore project at the desired location and transfer the data using the [Import/Export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) capability. A Firestore project's location is not currently possible to be changed.

This is the public documentation on [Firestore locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#types).

Just to clarify and complete my current response a little more, the only way to migrate your data (move your data) to another project at this time is manually using the managed export feature, as stated in this [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data), or using cloud functions to schedule exports, as stated in this other one [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#before_you_begin), and then importing the data into your [destination project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data#import_data_into_the_destination_project).

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately impossible to change the location of Firestore resource locations after setting up Functions, RTDB or Firestore. As per [The Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations), `Warning: Setting the location for one of these services (that is, Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage, or scheduled functions) also sets the location for the others. After you set your project's default GCP resource location, you cannot change it.`